# OSMDROID draw polyline from geometry

Tags: android, openlayers-3, osmdroid, polyline

Is it possible to draw a polilyne from a `route_geometry`?
In Open Layers 3 there is this example [Open Layers 3 Polyline from geometry](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/examples/feature-move-animation.html), but how do I achieve this in osmdroid?
I want to save each route geometry resolved by `roadManager` and then draw a polyline from it.

Comment: The example mentioned (ideally/should) gets a polyline route from a web service Geocoding service like [OSRM](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md) or [MapQuest](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/).

Comment: It is, `route_geometry` is resolved by a service, in this case a `RoadManager` of osmdroid.bonuspack library, it also returns a complete and more detailed ArrayList<GeoPoint> to draw the route. But my question is if there is a direct equivalent of the example because the encoded `geometry` is shorter than an array of geopoints and i like to store the route as a String